# Подскажите откуда берется при выводе Id= null Name= null

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
HashMap<Integer, String> map;
static Integer index;
static String name;

public Main() {
    map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(index, name);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main solution = new Main();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String name = reader.readLine();
        solution.map.put(index, name);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> pair : solution.map.entrySet()) {
        index = pair.getKey();
        name = pair.getValue();
        System.out.println("Id=" + index + " Name=" + name);
    }
}
```

[image: откуда берется при выводе Id= null Name= null]

Comment: Integer.parseInt() что возвращает?

Answer (score 4):

У вас две непроинициализированные статические переменные:

```
static Integer index;
static String name;
```

которые вы кладете в ваш `map` в конструкторе (по сути вы кладете ключ `null` со значением `null`):

```
public Main() {
    map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(index, name);
}
```

вот они у вас и выводятся

Если проинициализируете их:

```
static Integer index = 100500;
static String name = "Вася";
```

то выведется `Id=100500  Name=Вася`